Is it possible to automatically kill a k8s pod controlled by a job when the given config map changes?
I am aware of https://github.com/stakater/Reloader and use it to restart my deployments when configuration of interest changes.
However, I now have a different animal - a cronjob. The pods started by its jobs restart on failure. So when such a pod is deleted a new one is started in its place.
Hence the semantics I am searching for when the relevant configmap changes is:

If the cronjob does not have a job running at the moment - do nothing.
Otherwise, kill the job's pod. The pod will be restarted and use the updated config map.

How would you implement this semantics?

For a CronJob, I might do nothing, expecting that the underlying Pods will complete relatively quickly and it's acceptable to have the old configuration for a minute or two.

I understand that. But there could be circumstances when this semantics makes sense and so I am curious how would people go about implementing it. Of course, if no one ever needed it, then it is probably a dead end.
